# how to select from filtervalues where genre comma delimited values contain only what is selected

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

I have a list of products and services thats being fed into observables in knockout. Currently it works where the users selects from a list of genres and knockout returns a list of products that contains that genre in a comma delimited field.

Each product get fed into knockout as this:

```
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|       name        |               genre                |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
| Star Wars         | Sci-Fi, Action, Adventure, Blueray |
| Lord of the Rings | Fantasy, Fiction, Adventure, DVD   |
| Matrix            | Sci-Fi, Fantasy, Blueray           |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
```

and my checkbox list are as this in the view:

```
<div class="col-md-3 filterlist" >
<form name="specialties" action="" method="POST">
    <strong>Specialties</strong>
    <ul class="categorySearchList">


            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Sci-Fi" data-   bind="checked:filterValues" /> Sci-Fi</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Action" data-bind="checked:filterValues" /> Action</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Adventure" data-bind="checked:filterValues" /> Adventure</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Fantasy" data-bind="checked:filterValues" /> Fantasy</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Fiction" data-bind="checked:filterValues" /> Fiction</label></li>

    </ul>
    <hr />
    <strong>Type</strong>
    <ul class="categorySearchList">
       
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="DVD" data-bind="checked:filterValues " /> DVD</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Bluray" data-bind="checked:filterValues " /> Bluray</label></li>
        
    </ul>
</form>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="span8" style="float: left;">

<div data-bind="foreach: filterProducts">

    <div class="wrapp2 span2" style="margin: 12px 5px;">
        <p>
            <img src="~/Content/images/image.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="Product Name"/>
             <strong data-bind="text: genre"></strong>&nbsp;strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

and so on which outputs this:

☐ Sci-Fi

☐ Action

☐ Adventure

☐ Fantasy

☐ Fiction

---

☐ DVD

☐ Bluray

My knockout script is this:

```
function Program(course) {
this.name = course.Value;
this.genre = course.Text;
}


function ProgramModel() {

var self = this;
self.isLoading = ko.observable(true);
self.products = ko.observableArray();
self.filterValues = ko.observableArray(); 

$.getJSON("/extra/api/api/GetProductProgramList", function (data) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (course) {
        self.products.push(new Program(course));

    });
    self.isLoading(false);
});

self.filterProducts = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.products(),
    function (product) {
            var genreValues = product.genre.split(",");
            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(genreValues,
                function (genre) {
                    return self.filterValues.indexOf(genre.trim()) > -1;
                });
        if (match) {
            return match;
        }
    });
});

self.filter = function (genre) {
    self.currentFilter(genre);
};


}

ko.applyBindings(new ProgramModel());
```

So it works where the user selects a genre from the list and it displays. For example the user selects Sci-Fi and Star Wars and Matrix shows up, but then when the user selects Sci-Fi AND DVD all three show up. when really nothing should show up, because theres no sci-fi dvd in that list.

So i want to make it so that it splits the genres and only selects the ANDS of what was selected. Like if i selected Adventure AND Blueray; only Star Wars should appear.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the complete HTML binding mark up you used??

Comment: You need an observableArray of `selectedProducts`, which you use instead of `products` in your computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.filterProducts = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.products(),
    function (product) {
            var genreValues = product.genre.split(",");
            var matches = ko.utils.arrayFilter(genreValues, function (genre) {
                return self.filterValues.indexOf(genre.trim()) >= 0;
            });
            return matches.length == self.filterValues().length;
    });
});
```

Figured it out. it was as simple as just returning the match length with the filterValues!

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/7swLn92c/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function (product) {
    var genres = ko.utils.arrayForEach(product.genre.split(","),
        function(genre) { return genre.trim();});
    var filters = self.filterValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; ++i) {
        if (genres.indexOf(filters[i].trim()) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Might work if I understand what's going on correctly.  Basically, you need to check that every filter is present in the genre list of the product instead of just checking for one to be present.