# Knockoutjs: how to filter by genre AND by mediatype

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

6 days ago, I asked this question:

[how to select from filtervalues where genre comma delimited values contain only what is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238403/how-to-select-from-filtervalues-where-genre-comma-delimited-values-contain-only)

I arrived at an answer; and a fellow provided this fiddle with the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/7swLn92c/

---

But i ran into another issue. Although i have it searching the comma strings for matches and returning the length of matches equal to the array. This code is incomplete.

The objective is to have the user select multiple genres and those genres appear. But then when the user select the mediatype such as DVD or Bluray. the results should show all items from the genre as dvd and/or blueray.

for example:

users selects: Adventure, Sci-fi, and then Blueray; only Star Wars and Matrix should appear.

if user selects: Adventure, Sci-fi; Star Wars, Lord of the Rings, and Matrix should appear.

For choosing one match i used:

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(genreValues,
function (genre) {
return self.filterValues.indexOf(genre.trim()) > -1;});
if (match) {
   return match;
}
```

but for bringing up all matching results i used:

```
var matches = ko.utils.arrayFilter(genreValues, function (genre) { return 
self.filterValues.indexOf(genre.trim()) >= 0; });
return matches.length === self.filterValues().length;
```

Maybe there is a way i can combine them? here is my fiddle attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/0jr5Lc25/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    self.filterProducts = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.products(),function (product) {
        var genreValues = product.genre.split(",");
        var mediaValues = product.media;
        var genreMatch = false;
        var mediaMatch = false;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(genreValues, function (genre) {
            if( self.filterValues.indexOf(genre.trim()) >= 0){
                genreMatch = true;
            }
            //return self.filterValues.indexOf(genre.trim()) >= 0;
        });
        if(self.filterMedia().length === 0){
            mediaMatch = true;
        }
        if(self.filterValues().length === 0){
            genreMatch = true
        }
        // if string
        if(self.filterMedia().indexOf(mediaValues.trim()) >= 0){
          mediaMatch = true;
        }
        // if array
        //ko.utils.arrayForEach(mediaValues, function (media) {
            //if(self.filterMedia().indexOf(media.trim()) >= 0){
                //mediaMatch = true;
            //}
        //});
        if(genreMatch && mediaMatch){
        return true;
        } return false;
    });
});
```

You had a few issues;

1. ko.utils.arrayFilter only needs to be used once.
2. var mediamatches = ko.utils.arrayFilter(mediaValues ... was comparing to self.filterValues needed to be mediaValues.
3. BlueRay doesn't equal BluRay
4. Sci-Fi html checkbox was working corrected the html.

https://jsfiddle.net/0jr5Lc25/36/

Comment: Ah ok i cleaned it up. I also see your logic there. Thank you!